# create List button with lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

As present there is not an option to create list button with custom lightning component.
But i think i have seen same think in some org. But not available any more.
Is there any way we can create list button to add lightning component.

workaround -

1. Create vf page and add this page to list button and call lightning
   component using light out dependency.
2. create a visual flow , add the url in list button and call the flow
   using URL.

But is there any OOTB functionality present.